# Uniqueness of the cube root of a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices

After doing many calculus steps I found that $S^3=2I$ where $S\in \mathcal{M}_{m,m}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. So I'm wondering if I can write my solution $S\propto I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eigenvalues of S all have to be positive real cube roots of 2, so they are all equal. Since any symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, S must be the identity times the real cube root of 2, so S is unique.